# dataWithContentsOfURL vs NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I have a `NSOperation` subclass that runs in the background.  It is non-concurrent.  It downloads some data from a URL and then does some processing on the data.

Since it is already running in the background, I am using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL]` to download the data.  Is there any advantage to making the operation concurrent and using a `NSURLConnection`?

The downloads are small so I don't need to worry about pausing and continuing and I have error checking for the data in the processing.

Comment: Tiny tip: Are you using `+ dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` to handle any errors?

Comment: I will be if I am not convinced to switch to NSURLConnection :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, first let me say that implementing NSURLConnection as an operation it's little bit tricky, but it has a lot of advantages. First you can use callbacks, to manage authentications, upload bar, etc. Second you can manage multiple connection asynchronously on a secondary thread, with sync op you block the thread where the method is running in until it finishes.

Comment: Plus you can always use on of the several `NSURLConnection` wrappers, like `AFNetworking`, which make things much easier and abstract a lot away.